# Python: How to construct a tuple, value dictionary from a list of key,value dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of dicts as follows:

```
lst = [{'unitname':'unit1', 'test1': 2, 'test2': 9}, {'unitname':'unit2', 'test1': 24, 'test2': 35}]
```

How do I contruct a single dict as follows:

```
dictA = { ('unit1','test1'): 2, ('unit1','test2'): 9, ('unit2','test1'):24, ('unit2','test2' : 35 }
```

`

I have all the unit names & test names in a list:

```
unitnames = ['unit1','unit2']
testnames = ['test1','test2']
```

I tried but missed out some tests for some units.

```
dictA = {}
for unit in unitnames:
    for dict in lst:
        for k,v in dict.items():
            dictA[unit,k] = v
```

Advices? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dictA = {}
for d in lst:
    unit = d['unitname']
    for test in testnames:
        if test in d:
            dictA[unit,test] = d[test]
```

I'm assuming (1) that all the dicts in your list have a `unitname` key, (2) that its value is always one of the units you're interested in, (3) that some dicts in the list may have entries for tests you aren't interested in, and (4) that some tests you're interested in may be absent from some dicts in the list. Those assumptions are a bit arbitrary; if any happen to be wrong it shouldn't be hard to adjust the code for them.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
dictA = {}
for l in lst:
  name = l.pop('unitname')
  for test in l:
      dictA[name, test] = l[test]
```

---

Posted at the same time and with the same assumptions as Gareth's solution - however this will not give you the extra item of (name, 'unitname') = name

---

Marcelo Cantos's solution is quite elegant, but would be easier for mere mortals like us to parse like this:

```
dict(     ((d['unitname'], k), t)
     for d in lst
       for (k, t) in d.iteritems()
         if k != 'unitname'
    )
```

Comment: thanks. it works. didn't know 'pop' works for dictionaries in list. helpful!

Comment: @siva Gah! I didn't see that you had the test and unit names in a list when I posted, ergo my solution doesn't use them. :P IMHO duplicating this data seems pointless. As a warning, popping an item from a dict will mutate it in all scopes containing a reference to that dictionary. if you don't want this you  can do a shallow-copy of the dict by putting `l = l.copy()` on a line before `name = l.pop('unitname')`

Comment: In the list-comprehension form, you can't avoid the parentheses around the top-most expression. As-is, the code results in `SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument`.

Comment: ah sorry, I thought it only needed to be a tuple.The point about indentation still stands however.

Answer (score 2):

```
dict(((d['unitname'], k), t)
     for d in lst
     for (k, t) in d.iteritems()
     if k != 'unitname')
```

Comment: wow.. impressive! though takes time to digest the one-liner.. :) thanks. helpful!

Comment: This is impressive, and I'm sure would be a more performance-optimal solution than mine - it might be easier to understand if you formatted it differently (as if it's a normal for loop but with the content on top) I'll put a suggestion of this in my solution.